# Function which returns datatable

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which returns datatable

```
  Private Function _Read() As DataTable
    Dim _cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim _da As New SqlDataAdapter(_cmd)
    Dim _dt As New DataTable
    With _cmd
        .Connection = dbRoot
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table "
    End With

    Try
        _da.Fill(_dt)
        Return _dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Now i want to get control if error ocurs so i put the code inside the Try Catch block.

How can i check from my program did exception happend ?

Can i set like this

```
IF _Read = nothing ?
```

Comment: `returnedDT = _Read() // If returnedDT IsNot Nothing Then...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to check if _Read returned nothing, you have to use the Is keyword in vb.net :

```
If _Read Is nothing Then
...
End if
```

But If you really want to "get control if error occurs" then the first thing you have to do is apply proper error handling.  Never catch and ignore exceptions.
A way to handle the exception is to notify the user through a message box, log it. Another option is not to have a Catch in the procedure so that the error is propagated up the stack.

Also, you may want to have a finally block to close and release resources, or use a using construct. See here : [SqlCommand (Using Statement / Disposing issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498599/sqlcommand-using-statement-disposing-issue)

Comment: How can i set if its not nothing ?

Comment: If _Read IsNot Nothing Then

Answer (score 1):

Try below variation of _Read method. This method returns DataTable as return type and error message as output parameter. I hope this will help.

```
Private Function _Read(ByRef errorMsg As String) As DataTable

    Try
        'Get data from datrabase

        'return datatable
        _Read = New Data.DataTable

        'return empty if no error occured
        errorMsg = ""

    Catch ex As Exception

        'return null data table
        _Read = Nothing

        'return error code
        errorMsg = ex.Message

    End Try

End Function
```

Call this method in you code as

```
    Dim myDataTable As Data.DataTable
    Dim myErrorMsg As String = ""

    myDataTable = _Read(myErrorMsg)

    If myErrorMsg <> "" Then
        MessageBox.Show(myErrorMsg)
    End If
```